# Bash: Find all files with specific extension and rename them according to first line of content within each file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I know these are asked a lot, but I had trouble coming up with the correct script for this.

I tried to use:

```
for fname in find . -type f -name "*.txt"; do mv $fname $(grep -m 1 "specific text" *.txt).txt; done
```

But I could not get it to work right.

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Based on what you wrote, I think you need to put the find command inside $() so the result is evaluated and passed to the for loop. However, it's not completely from your question what grep -m 1 "specific text" is supposed to do. That's not going to find the first line of content - that's going to return the first match of "specific text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
  for file; do
    if newname=$(grep -m1 "specific text" "$file"); then
       echo mv -i "$file" "${file%/*}/${newname}.txt" 
    fi
  done
' sh {} +
```

This only renames files matching the `grep` pattern. The parameter expansion `${file%/*}` removes the filename from the path and leaves the directory part of `$file` and option `-i` prompts to overwrite an already existing file.

If the output looks as expected, then remove the `echo` before the `mv` and run the command again to rename the files.

Comment: You're welcome! Please have a look at the help center what to do if an answer is helpful: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).